# how to get array values, on input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

So I have multiple table data insert I want to get input value on some field so I can calculate on another field. How can I do that if that is an array field?

I've tried using javascript but it's only working on first field (not array field).

```js
function tot() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('total').value = result;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-add-form").click(function(){
        var addi = parseInt($("#addi-form").val());
        var nextform = addi + 1;
        $("#insert-form").append("<b>Item Price " + nextform + " :</b>" +
            "<input type='text' name='names[]' required>"
            "<input id='price' type='text' name='price[]' onkeyup='tot();' required>"
            "<input id='qty' type='text' name='qty[]' onkeyup='tot();' required>"
            "<input type='text' name='total[]' required>"
        $("#addi-form").val(nextform);
    });
    $("#btn-reset-form").click(function(){
        $("#insert-form").html("");
        $("#addi-form").val("1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn-add-form">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-reset-form">Reset</button><br><input type="text" name="names[]" required>
<input id="price" type="text" name="price[]" onkeyup="tot();" required>
<input id="qty" type="text" name="qty[]" onkeyup="tot();" required>
<input id="total" type="text" name="total[]" required>
<div id="insert-form"></div>
```

I expect that way works on added array table but it's not, it only affects field on my first table.

Comment: What do you mean by `array field`?. You mean you want to get the value of `input` with name attribute like `name="price[]"`.

Comment: yes that's what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign the same `ID` to multiple DOM elements on the same page. I have updated your code a bit to use the item number with the `ID`. Like, for item 1 `ID` is `price`, for item 2 `ID` is `price-2`, for item 3 `ID` is `price-3` and so on. Same done with `qty` and `total`.

You may try this code:

```js
function sum_total() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    var calcTotalSum = document.getElementsByClassName("calc-total");
    var totalItems = calcTotalSum.length;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < totalItems) {
        if (calcTotalSum[i].value !== "") {
            totalSum = totalSum + parseInt(calcTotalSum[i].value);
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    if(totalSum > 0) {
        console.log("Total Sum is: ", totalSum);
    }
}

function tot(event) {
    var itemNo = event.target.getAttribute("data-item");
    var txtFirstNumberValue = "";
    var txtSecondNumberValue = "";    
    if (itemNo) {
        txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('price-' + itemNo).value;
        txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('qty-' + itemNo).value;        
    } else {
        txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('price').value;
        txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    }
    
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        if (itemNo) {
            document.getElementById('total-' + itemNo).value = result;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('total').value = result;
        }
    }
    
    sum_total();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-add-form").click(function(){
        var addi = parseInt($("#addi-form").val());
        var nextform = addi + 1;
        $("#insert-form").append("<b>Item Price " + nextform + " :</b>" +
            "<input type='text' name='names[]' required>" +
            "<input id='price-" + nextform + "' data-item='" + nextform + "' type='text' name='price[]' onkeyup='tot(event);' required>" +
            "<input id='qty-" + nextform + "' data-item='" + nextform + "' type='text' name='qty[]' onkeyup='tot(event);' required>" +
            "<input id='total-" + nextform + "' class='calc-total' type='text' name='total[]' required>"
        );
        $("#addi-form").val(nextform);
    });
    $("#btn-reset-form").click(function(){
        $("#insert-form").html("");
        $("#addi-form").val("1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn-add-form">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-reset-form">Reset</button><br>
<input type="hidden" name="addi-form" id="addi-form" value=1 required>
<input type="text" name="names[]" required>
<input id="price" type="text" name="price[]" onkeyup="tot(event);" required>
<input id="qty" type="text" name="qty[]" onkeyup="tot(event);" required>
<input id="total" class="calc-total" type="text" name="total[]" required>
<div id="insert-form"></div>
```

Hope, it helps you.

**EDITED:** sum_total function to calculate the sum of the total amount.

Comment: So, if I want to totaling that total field what should I do ?

Comment: @blackwave When you like to make the total of the totaling field? I mean, on which event?

Comment: Is it possible to do that on same event ? 
if i make a field 'sum_total' to contain 'total-1, total-2, total-3' ... will that work ?
when 'total' field calculated, so does 'sum_total' field.

Comment: @blackwave Added `sum_total` which calculates the sum of the total. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to trigger the `tot()` function on the newly added table rows. For that purpose you need to:

1. call `tot()` function to bind to the newly added elements after they have been `appended`. Or use the jQuery bind method.
2. Use *.class* in place of *#id* attributes on the elemnts so that you can iterate through all of them using the class selector